# C++: safe usage of vsprintf

Tags: c++, variadic-functions

I have a largish code base that does `log_msg("Here comes %s", "the text")`, where `log_message` is a macro that adds function name and line numbers to the log message.

GCC/G++ warn about errors when the format string doesn't match the supplied arguments. Unfortunately sometimes the code calls `log_msg(get_the_text())`. The return value of `get_the_text()` is unknown at compile time, so if it contains some `printf` formatting sequences, the code will fall flat on its face.

What I'm looking for is a way to route the single argument usages through a different code path that doesn't interpret the formatting codes. I tried something like this hoping that the non-variadic case is more specific than the variadic one:

```
void log_the_message_implementation(const char *filename, const char *funcname, const char *msg);
void log_the_message_implementation(const char *filename, const char *funcname, const char *msg, ...);
```

I was hoping that the compiler would pick the single argument function when there are no variable args, but it complains about ambiguous calls.

Any ideas how to fix this without changing thousands of calls from
`log_msg(get_the_text())` to `log_msg("%s", get_the_text())`?

Comment: There is no "safe usage of vsprintf". To implement this safely in C++, you ***will*** have to change those thousands of calls to use C++'s type-safe iostreams. In most cases it should be possible to write a simple script to do most of the dirty work. It's fairly likely that an overwhelming majority of these kinds of logging calls follow the same format that's eminently transmogrifiable by a script into `std::cerr << whatever`, or whichever logging file descriptor is used. And a little bit of manual cleanup to fix up references that don't follow the common format.

Comment: @HansPassant That is exactly why I'm looking for a safer solution that bypasses the printf formatting for uses without additional parameters besides the initial string.

Comment: log_msg_noformat(get_the_text()) and use your text editor's Replace All command to make that quick.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik If not safe, than at least safer. I really don't want to touch code owned by others. I'm hoping for a solution that only affects the implementation of the logging code, not the callers.

Comment: There is no easy solution. This is old C-style, type-unsafe formatting. A plain function that has C-style varargs has no means of determining how many actual arguments it gets. The closest that comes to mind is that some time ago I implemented a similar logging facility as a template with a variadic parameter pack. It captured the parameter to the now-template, so it new how many parameters it had and what type they are. Then it parsed the formatting string and implemented all the substitutions by itself. Lots of code, but it was type-safe and bullet proof.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik That might work. Count the arguments and then pass it on to either the printf based code or not. I'll have to think about that.

Comment: @jpo234: If you manage to write an answer yourself, it's perfectly OK to put in the answers below. Now this looks like a question without answer, so someone with a similar question may overlook it.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik: Let's not get dramatic. The safe solution is `boost::format`, which will handle `sprintf` format strings.  No complex script, just a slightly different macro implementation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to @SamVarshavchik this is what I came up with:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdio>
#include <tuple>


template<typename ... Args>
void log(Args ... args) {
    if (sizeof...(args) == 1) {
        auto t = std::make_tuple(args...);
        std::puts(std::get<0>(t));
    } else {
        std::printf(args...);
    }
}

int
main() {
    log("Test %d");
    log("%s %d\n", "Test", 1);
    log([]{ return "%s";}());
    return 0;
}
```